# Java 8 Stream - How to return replace a strings contents with a list of items to find

Tags: java, foreach, java-8, java-stream

I wish to replace the code below using java8 .stream()
 or .foreach(). However I am having trouble doing this.

Its probably very easy, but I'm finding the functional way of thinking a struggle :)

I can iterate, no problem but the but returning the modified string is the issue due  to mutability issues.

Anyone have any ideas ?

```
List<String> toRemove = Arrays.asList("1", "2", "3");
String text = "Hello 1 2 3";

for(String item : toRemove){
    text = text.replaceAll(item,EMPTY);
}
```

Thanks !

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Wow, you guys like doing things the hard way. this is what filter() and collect() are for.

```
List<String> toRemove = Arrays.asList("1", "2", "3");
String text = "Hello 1 2 3";

text = Pattern.compile("").splitAsStream(text)
    .filter(s -> !toRemove.contains(s))
    .collect(Collectors.joining());
System.out.println("\"" + text + "\"");
```

outputs (as the original code did)

```
"Hello   "
```

Of course, if your search strings are longer than one character, the previous method works better. If you have a tokenized string, though, split and join is easier.

```
List<String> toRemove = Arrays.asList("12", "23", "34");
String text = "Hello 12 23 34 55";
String delimiter = " ";

text = Pattern.compile(delimiter).splitAsStream(text)
    .filter(s -> !toRemove.contains(s))
    .collect(Collectors.joining(delimiter));
System.out.println("\"" + text + "\"");
```

outputs

```
"Hello 55"
```

Comment: Excellent! That looks the best solution so far. I'm getting the grips of things now. Nice work !

Comment: Except that creating a temporary array via `String.split` holding all elements is exactly the opposite of using the `Stream` API. It could be a good answer if it was using [`Pattern.compile(delimiter).splitAsStream(text)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#splitAsStream-java.lang.CharSequence-), still not exactly what the question was about, but never mind.

Comment: It will also be significantly more efficient if you have a list of more than a few items to remove to store them as a Set<String> rather than a List<String> since .contains() on a Set is far more efficient.

Comment: Your answer only works for single characters or when there's delimiters. Holger's answer is more general (your answer doesn't work for me)

Answer (score 38):

Since you can’t use the stream to modify the `text` variable you have to coerce the operation into one `Function` which you can apply to the `text` to get the final result:

```
List<String> toRemove = Arrays.asList("1", "2", "3");
String text = "Hello 1 2 3";
text=toRemove.stream()
             .map(toRem-> (Function<String,String>)s->s.replaceAll(toRem, ""))
             .reduce(Function.identity(), Function::andThen)
             .apply(text);
```

Comment: Excellent, I have never seen Function.identity(), Function::andThen in use before. Nice work.

Comment: @Holger or (as you have shown me this before) : `.reduce(Function::andThen).orElse(Function.identity())` 1+

Comment: I dont get it yet, but worked for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

```
text = toRemove.stream()
               .reduce(text, (str, toRem) -> str.replaceAll(toRem, ""));
```

would work for you.

Comment: Could you please [edit] in an explanation of why this code answers the question? Code-only answers are [discouraged](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/148272/274165), because they don't teach the solution.

Comment: This won't work if the stream is parallel.

Answer (score 2):

If I understood you correctly, you want to do something like this:

```
toRemove.forEach(removeString -> {
    text = text.replaceAll(removeString, "");
});
```

The only problem is, that you can't. :(

You can read about it here: http://javarevisited.blogspot.co.il/2014/02/10-example-of-lambda-expressions-in-java8.html

Section 6: `One restriction with lambda expression is that, you can only reference either final or effectively final local variables, which means you cannot modified a variable declared in the outer scope inside a lambda.`

**EDIT**

You can do something very ugly. Like this:

```
private static String text;

public void main (String[] args) {
    text = "Hello 1 2 3";
    List<String> toRemove = Arrays.asList("1", "2", "3");
    toRemove.forEach(removeString -> replaceTextWithEmptyString(removeString));
}

private static void replaceTextWithEmptyString(String whatToReplace) {
    text = text.replaceAll(whatToReplace, "");
}
```

Comment: Thats what I was getting, I wondered if there was away around by doing it differently. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: @SteveG Please see my edit. But keep in mind, that this solution is (very) ugly.

Comment: Cool, It also separates the concern, which if it was a complicated method would be good.

Answer (score 0):

```
List<String> versions = new ArrayList<>();
    versions.add("Lollipop");
    versions.add("KitKat");
    versions.add("Jelly Bean");
    versions.add("Ice Cream Sandwidth");
    versions.add("Honeycomb");
    versions.add("Gingerbread");

    System.out.println("Data");
    versions.stream().filter(s -> s.startsWith("G")).map(i->i.replace("G", "bn")).forEach(System.out::println);

}
```