# java8 reduce with useless combiner

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, reduce

I need to apply a list of regex to a string, so I thought to use java8 map reduce:

```
List<SimpleEntry<String, String>> list = new ArrayList<>();

list.add(new SimpleEntry<>("\\s*\\bper\\s+.*$", ""));
list.add(new SimpleEntry<>("\\s*\\bda\\s+.*$", ""));
list.add(new SimpleEntry<>("\\s*\\bcon\\s+.*$", ""));

String s = "Tavolo da cucina";

String reduced = list.stream()
    .reduce(s, (v, entry) -> v.replaceAll(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue()) , (c, d) -> c);
```

Actually this code may be is not very beautiful, but it works. I know this cannot be parallelised and for me is ok.

Now my question is: is there any chance with Java8 (or higher version) to write something more elegant? I mean also avoiding to add the useless combiner function.

Comment: What is this code supposed to do? To remove all the words from the string which at least one character is matched with any character from `bper`, `bda` or `bcon`?

Comment: @Eugene it does, `replaceAll` returns a new `String` each time.

Comment: Sorry, but I isn't simple loop enough? Why involve streams if you don't use their benefits like parallelism, filtering, etc? Why not use something like `for (SimpleEntry<> entry : list){s = s.replaceAll(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());}`?

Comment: @Pshemo yes, but it is not fun :) ... well, to be honest I'm just playing (and learning) java8 stream.

Comment: `(c, d) -> c` will give invalid results for parallel processing, you are better if throwing an `Exception` in the form of `(c, d) -> throw new AssertionError("Not for parallel") `

Comment: I found a very interesting [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24011597/java-8-stream-how-to-return-replace-a-strings-contents-with-a-list-of-items-to#answer-24013344), written by Holger.

Comment: @Eugene thanks, it make sense.

Comment: but watch it... read this also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29210176/can-a-collectors-combiner-function-ever-be-used-on-sequential-streams

Comment: @Oleksandr very very interesting, thanks... although I'm still not sure I got Holger answer :))

Comment: @freedev You `map` a pattern to a `Function`, reducing it all to a composed function like `x.andThen(y).apply(inputStr)` applying it to an input string in the end.

Comment: @Oleksandr thanks, inspired by your comment, I tried to answer to my own questions.

Comment: As side note, the patterns suggest that you are actually intend to do `replaceFirst`.

Comment: @Holger looking only at the regexs I wrote in the question you're right, but the idea was to have the chance to run many kind of regexs, an in some case there could be more matching occurrences.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inspired by Oleksandr's comment and Holger I wrote this

```
String reduced = list.stream()
.map(entry-> 
    (Function<String, String>) v -> v.replaceAll(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue()))
.reduce(Function.identity(), Function::andThen)
.apply(s);
```

This also reduce all entries to a function composition.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another, interesting approach: reduce all entries to a function composition, then apply that composed function on the original input:

```
String result = list.stream()
        .map(entry -> 
            (Function<String, String>) text -> 
                       text.replaceAll(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue()))
        //following op also be written as .reduce(Function::compose) (see comment by Eugene)
        .reduce((f1, f2) -> f1.andThen(f2)) //compose functions
        .map(func -> func.apply(s)) //this basically runs all `replaceAll`
        .get();
```

The result of this is your expected string. While this function composition is not intuitive, it nonetheless seems to fit the idea that your original list is in fact a sort of "transformation logic" chain.

Comment: `(f1, f2) -> f1.compose(f2)` can be replaced with `Function::compose`, or even better `Function::andThen` I guess

Comment: The difference between `andThen` and `compose` is the order in which the functions are applied. If you want to do `f` before `g` you have to use `f.andThen(g)` or `g.compose(f)`.

Comment: @ErnestKiwele another smallish problem is when you have an empty `List`, this can be written as `... .reduce(Function::andThen).orElse(Function.identity()).apply(s);` I did not compile this btw, just looks like it would work

Comment: @Holger Right, `compose` will make functions run from last to first, but this all doesn't matter in this case because all `replaceAll` functions will be executed and the result will be the same. But that's a good observation, thanks