# How to map nested PlaceHolders of a string to Pojo class in java

Tags: java

I am reading data from file and I need to replace the placeholders with the java Bean values.

I have tried the `StrSubstitutor` to map the values but it did not worked, might me my approach is not right and declaration of placeholders are right please suggest me the right way

```
Class Test{
    String firstName;
    Request request;
}
```

```
class Request {
    String requestNumber;
}
```

```
setValues(){
    String template ="Dear ${test.firstname},Your Request number is ${test.request.requestNumber}.";
    Test test= test;
    Map<String, String> valuesMap = new HashMap<>();
    valuesMap.put("test.firstname",test.getFirstName());
    valuesMap.put("test.request.requestNumber",test.getRequest().getRequestNumber());
    StrSubstitutor StrSubstitutor = new StrSubstitutor(valuesMap);
    String mailContent = StrSubstitutor.replace(template );
}
```

**Output should be**

Dear firstName,Your Request number is 1234567.

Answer (score 0):

You can basically replace each key by the value

```java
String template ="Dear ${test.firstname},Your Request number is ${test.request.requestNumber}.";
Test test = ...;

Map<String, String> valuesMap = new HashMap<>();
valuesMap.put("test.firstname",test.getFirstName());
valuesMap.put("test.request.requestNumber",test.getRequest().getRequestNumber());

for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : map.entrySet()) {
    template = template.replace("${" + entry.getKey() + "}", entry.getValue());
}
```

Check this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18601011/replace-string-values-with-value-in-hash-map) for more answers

Comment: if i have 100 fields in the object then i have to put 100 times the keys into the valuesMap,
i want a solution so that i don't need to put the 100 keys to my Map and directly i can replace the xPaths provided into the template with objects