# How to replace some words with given replacement map in java?

Tags: java, replace, hashmap

egg:

```
String str = "Don't trouble trouble until trouble troubles you"
Map<String,String> replacementMap = new HashMap<String,String>(){{put("trouble","replaceStr");}};
```

I want the output was:

```
"Don't troubleStr troubleStr until troubleStr troubles you."
```

The scene is i have a paragraph and i also have a keywords database ,when i show the paragraph in web page,i want to highlight the matched keywords and replace a link target.

Comment: A similar question has been answered before: [Replace String values with value in Hash Map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18601011/replace-string-values-with-value-in-hash-map)

Comment: You need to show a more accurate example of what effect you want on the String input and show some effort in coding a solution, or your question will be closed as a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

```
  String str = "Don't trouble trouble until trouble troubles you";
    Map<String,String> replacementMap = new HashMap<String, String>(){{put("trouble","replaceStr");}};
    for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : replacementMap.entrySet()) {
        System.out.println(entry.getKey()); //trouble
        System.out.println(entry.getValue()); // replaceStr
        str = str.replace(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
    }
    System.out.println(str);
```

Comment: The scene is i have a paragraph and i also have a keywords database ,when i show the paragraph in web page,i want to highlight the matched keywords and replace a link target.Ablove maybe too simple for my scene.

Comment: what do u mean by replace link target ?